# can 5mm HDD slot accommodate 7 mm HDD

Tags: hard-drive, sony-vaio

My HDD just crashed. I am using sony vaio SVN15135CN which had Hitachi Z5K500-500 HDD and Intel HM76 Express Chipset. I want to buy a new one from segate or WD.

Below is the product page:
http://www.sony.co.in/product/sve15135cn

In the HDD bay the HDD is hold by a steel frame (don't now if that is called caddy) whose depth seems to be 1 cm so I think it can fit 7mm or 9mm 2.5 inch HDD. I just want to confirm if that's possible. I could not find this information on sony website. Also, can I use 7200RPM 6Gbps SATA HDD? Current is 5200RPM 3Gbps.

One last thing, will I be able to install the OS from the recovery disks I made from the earlier HDD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t see how the slot is 5mm. That’s not a common disk height anyway. 9.5 mm is “full height”, 7 mm is “reduced height” and 12.5mm is “extended height”. Apparently, there actually are some disks with 5 mm height, but I guess that form factor is virtually irrelevant.

Your [current disk](http://www.hgst.com/hard-drives/mobile-drives/7mm-thin-and-light-drives/travelstar-z5k500) is 7mm in height, so any drive like that will fit. All other specs are irrelevant. SATA is fully compatible both ways.

Whether you’ll be able to restore the recovery system depends. Theoretically yes, but there may be some kind of lock, though I doubt it.

Update: Oh yeah, and if you have enough money, go for a SSD. It’ll speed up your device tremendously.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I think ques is not clear enough. By 5mm slot I meant my HDD is of 5mm(I think I remembered wrong :( ) so the slot which is holding that can it also hold 7 or 9 mm? But my HDD is already 7mm :) so I am safe buying that.

Comment: While a 9 mm HDD might fit, I wouldn’t buy one. There’s plenty of 7 mm HDDs available, so play it safe.